# How to enable swash in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Can you help me enable swash button please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swashes are only available if the font file itself contains swash glyphs.

There are multiple places around the web where one could get "Bromello" -- from free font sites to paid sites.

From what I can tell, *most*, if not all, the free sites only offer only the core glyphs for Bromello. Paid sites seem to offer a wider array of glyphs for their versions of Bromello, including swashes and ligatures.

You may not have access to swashes due to *where* you got Bromello.